# Aggregate datatable with percentage for grouped elements dc.js

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

How to display failure % in the data table? I have the following csv and I am calculating the percentage of failures for each "name" field , I want to display the total failure percentage for each "name" in datatable

```
Customer | year| Week |Failure_Reason|     name        |    Type  |   Count 
___________________________________________________________________________
A         2018  29      D              Express Air        PR         27
___________________________________________________________________________
A         2018  26      M              Express Air        PR         58
___________________________________________________________________________
A         2018  26      D              Domestic                      5
___________________________________________________________________________
A         2018  27      N              Domestic          SPEED       29
___________________________________________________________________________
A         2018  30    Missed           International     PR          11
___________________________________________________________________________
A         2018  32      N              Domestic          PR          53
```

Code for the dimesion and group:

```
        var ndx= crossfilter(data);
        var all= ndx.groupAll();  
        var CTypedim=ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d["name"]+ ',' + d["Customer"];})
        var CTypeGroup=CTypedim.group();

        var percentFailures = CTypedim.group().reduce(
        function(p, v) {
             p.counter+= Number(v.count);
             p.failures += Number(v.Failure_Reason != 'N' ? v.count : 0);
             p.failPercent = p.counter ? p.failures/p.counter : 0;
             return p;
         },
         function(p, v) {

             p.counter-= Number(v.count);
             p.failures -= Number(v.Failure_Reason != 'N' ? v.count : 0);
             p.failPercent = p.counter ? p.failures/p.counter : 0;
             return p;
         },
         function() {
             return {
                 counter: 0,
                 failures: 0,
                 failPercent: 0
             };
         });

        dataTable.width(800).height(800)
        .dimension(percentFailures)
        .group(function(d) { return "" })
        .size(100)
        .columns([
            function(d) { return d.Customer; },
            function(d) { return d.year; },
            function(d) { return d.value.failpercent*100; },
            function(d) { return d.name; },

        ])
        .sortBy(function(d){ return d.year; })
        .order(d3.descending);
```

Need to display aggregated datavtable as follows:

```
Customer | Year| Failure%|     name        |    
_____________________________________________
A         2018      100%     Express Air       
_____________________________________________
A         2018      5.7%       Domestic     
_____________________________________________
A         2018      100%      International       
_____________________________________________
```

[image: Result]

Comment: It isn't clear to me if you want to show the raw data or aggregated data in your table. From your example, it looks like maybe you want to aggregate by both Customer and name, calculate failure for each customer/name combo, and display that. In which case you can create a group which reduces each of the columns you would like to see, and [pass the group as the dimension](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.dataTable.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, keep going!

You'll need to use the aggregated fields in your table:

```
    .columns([
        function(d) { return d.key.split(',')[1]; }, // customer part of multikey
        function(d) { return d.year; },
        function(d) { return d.value.failPercent*100; }, // capitalize consistently
        function(d) { return d.key.split(',')[0]; }, // name part of multikey

    ])
```

Using the year is problematic! Because once you aggregate, you don't really know what year each aggregated value represents - and it may represent multiple years. If you can drop that column, I recommend it.